# How does one hide the vertical bars that VS Code puts after curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How does one hide the vertical bars that VS Code puts after curly braces? In the screen shot there is one right below `while`, another one below `for`, and one after the two if-statements each. Is there a way to hide them?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Look at the `indent guides` settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found it thanks to @Mark. Go to Settings, search for *indent guide*. Under *Editor: Render Indent Guides* uncheck *Controls whether the editor should render indent guides*.